# Sequelize-Auto: Changing Postgres Table Schemas

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

My co-worker have created a complex database in Postgres, and I'm trying define all the models automatically using Sequelize and Sequelize-Auto.

This database have many schemas, but with Sequelize-auto I'm only can automatize the "public" schema.

How I could moving me to another schemas in sequelize-auto?

Answer (score 1):

just add the schema to options **sequelize.define('name', {attributes},{options}).**

make sure that you defined the schema before creating your Model.

```
var Project = sequelize.define('project', {
 title: Sequelize.STRING,
 description: Sequelize.TEXT
},
{
 schema: 'schema_name',
 ...
}
);
```